# Missing Run And Debug Launch Configuration button in VS Code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I have the following situation.

I cannot change launch Dart configurations anymore since the button is missing.
I think I hid it by accident but I cannot make it appear anymore.

[image]

Launch.json is still accessible but the button has disappeared.

Any help is appreciated, I don't really want to reinstall VS Code and I don't think it would help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found out how to restore the button's position.

Type the keyboard combination to start a `Command` (e.g.Command + Shift + P on MacOS) and run the command `View: Reset All Menus`.
This'll make the hidden view reappear.
The option to hide it is called `Hide 'Start Debugging'` and it cannot be found in the settings, so you have to reset the views to make it reappear.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative, if anyone else is facing this: If you right-click the gear and check "Start debugging" then that should bring it back. Despite the name, it won't actually start a debugging session!

Comment: No. I doesn't work, at all. Well, at least it didn't for me, but the reset all menus as proposed in another answers here, worked!

Answer (score 1):

if resetting the menu from command option by pressing:  Ctrl + Shift + P and typing the command View: Reset All Menus may work. In case it didn't I suggest you to open a seperate command line i.e CMD or Terminal in VS Code itself then typing the command Flutter Run may help. Also you can press in the terminal R to hot reload your flutter, dart app.